# Can not connect to wifi modem admin interface

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, modem, wifi-configuration

I want to view my TP-Link Wi-Fi modem setting page in my browser.This is my network information:

[image]

As you see my router IP is 192.168.1.1. When I ping this IP I get "request timed out" as result. When I enter the address in (Any) browser (in Google Chrome) I get "This webpage is not available." as result.

6 month ago was the last time I viewed modem interface setting page. It is worth to mention that i have internet connection!

Also this is my `arp -a`:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried it over a wired connection? Some WiFi can block attempted access to the settings page over WiFi itself.

Comment: @Tetsujin: Yes, I got same result.

Comment: Then that may not be its address. Maybe try arp -a & see if you can discover it that way. I don't have direct experience with a combo-router/wifi, mine APs are separate devices & their IP addresses are arbitrary

Comment: @Tetsujin, I forgot to say that I have internet connection. I updated the question with arp result.

Comment: All I can see there is the single usable address, plus some broadcast & network stuff, so theoretically it ought to be on 192.168.1.1 Those higher addresses are all innocuous, but not the addresses we're looking for. Unless you've done a lot of tweaking on the router, I'd go for a hard factory reset on it [remember to change the password if you do]

Comment: @Tetsujin, Appreciate your helps. I will wait for answers if I didn't get any, I will going to reset the modem.

Comment: Wish you luck :)

Answer (score 0):

I hard reset my modem using a needle and now I can connect to the modem.